# In postgresql, Why is _PG_init called twice?

Tags: postgresql, function

I wrote a c funtion in postgresql. This is my init function:

```
void _PG_init(){
  int line = 0, errcode2 = 0;
  char buf[1024], db_log[1024];
  dbglog("first call\n");

  l = (local_t*)palloc(sizeof(local_t));
  if(!l) die(ERROR_NOMEM);
  dbglog("first palloc local_t\n");
  memset(l, 0, sizeof(local_t));
  session_init_lock = 0;

  sprintf(buf, "%s/" PREFIX "/privacyprot.log", getenv("HOME"));
  l->logfile = fopen(buf, "a+");
  if(!(l->logfile)) die(ERROR_NOMEM);
  l->begin_time = time(NULL);
  return;
```

}

I know when this lib is first loaded, _PG_init will be called immediately, however, "first call" log is printed twice. How to solve this, I just want one single thread.

Comment: This might not be the problem, but perhaps you forgot to use include guards? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: @Wolph Thanks, perhaps you didn't understand me. In [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/xfunc-c.html), it says "Optionally, a dynamically loaded file can contain initialization and finalization functions. If the file includes a function named _PG_init, that function will be called immediately after loading the file. ..."  However,  my _PG_init function would be called twice, since I have a global unique memory to store infomation, if it called twice, there will be problem, how can I ensure it called only one time.

Comment: It'll be called once per backend load. If you wish to avoid that you must have it loaded by `shared_preload_libraries`. Note that individual backends can't share each others' memory, and that memory allocated at shared_preload_libraries before fork() time will be copy-on-write on individual backends after they fork() from the postmaster. PostgreSQL is a *multi-process architecture*.

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks，is there any configuration to set only one process？

Comment: @linuxie No, single-process is fundamentally not possible with PostgreSQL's architecture. You can use shared memory to co-ordinate between backend processes though. There are some examples of shared memory use in extensions in contrib/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably see it being called twice because of how you're testing.

It's called once per backend process, when it's loaded into that process by an explicit `LOAD` call, by `local_preload_libraries`, or by calling a `LANGUAGE c` function that refers to that shared library.

Yes, per-process. PostgreSQL is a *multi-process architecture*, with one `fork()`ed connection per process. Each backend can read postmaster memory since `fork()` makes it copy-on-write, but as writes copy the page into the process's private address space the processes cannot communicate by writing to global variables like in a multithreaded program. Instead they communicate using explicitly allocated shared memory segments. This is a shared-nothing-by-default model, as opposed to the shared-everything-by-default model of multithreaded programming.

If you want `PG_init` to be called exactly once you must use `shared_preload_libraries` to cause your library to be loaded by the postmaster when it starts, before backends get `fork()`ed. In this context it doesn't have access to databases or all the usual facilities, so it mostly registers hooks and callbacks, requests shared memory segment and lock allocations, then continues normal startup. You might also register background worker processes at this stage.

By requesting its own shared memory during postmaster start your extension can then use this memory, along with the other IPC mechanisms PostgreSQL provides like locks and latches, to communicate between backends.

You will find some examples of basic use of shared memory in extensions in the `contrib/` directory.

See:

- [Developer FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ)
- [Development information](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Development_information)
- [Developer page](http://www.postgresql.org/developer/)

and the various resources linked from there.